Bootstrap modal stuck on the first message in Angular
The modal only works with the first message, if I send a new one, this does not appear.
I am using:
Angular 17
Bootstrap 5.3
This is the ts file
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { UserService } from '../../services/user/user.service';
import { iUserDTO } from '../../models/iUserDTO';
import * as bootstrap from 'bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users-add',
  templateUrl: './users-add.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users-add.component.css']
})
export class UsersAddComponent {
  myForm: FormGroup;
  modalMessage: string = '';
  modalHeader: string = '';
  identificationNumber = 0;
  names = '';
  surnames = '';
  isUserMaster = '';

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private userService: UserService,    
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
  ) {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      identificationNumber: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[0-9]+$'), Validators.maxLength(25)]],
      firstName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z ]+$'), Validators.maxLength(100)]],
      lastName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(100)]],
      userMaster: ['no', Validators.required]
    });
  }

  private showModal(message: string, header: string): void {
    this.modalMessage = message;    
    this.modalHeader = header;
    const modalElement = document.getElementById('errorModal');
    
    if (modalElement) {
      const modal = new bootstrap.Modal(modalElement);      
      modal.show();

      // Add event listener to reset form when modal is closed
      modalElement.addEventListener('hidden.bs.modal', () => {                
        
        if(header === 'Éxito'){
          this.resetForm();
        }
        modal.dispose();          
      }, { once: true });
    } else {
      console.error('No se encontró el elemento modal con id "errorModal".');
    }    
  } 

  private resetForm(): void {
    const userMasterValue = this.myForm.get('userMaster')?.value;
    this.myForm.reset({
      identificationNumber: '',
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      userMaster: userMasterValue
    });    
  }

  onSubmit() {
    if (this.myForm.valid) {      

      const user: iUserDTO = {
        IdUser: 0,
        IdentificationNumber: this.myForm.value.identificationNumber,
        Names: this.myForm.value.firstName,
        Surnames: this.myForm.value.lastName,
        UserMaster: this.myForm.value.userMaster === 'yes'
      };

      this.userService.saveData(user).subscribe(
        response => {          
          this.showModal(response.message, 'Éxito');
        },
        error => {
          const errorMessage = error.error?.message || 'Error desconocido';
          this.showModal(errorMessage, 'Error');
        }
      );
    } else {
      this.showModal('Formulario inválido', 'Error');
    }
  }
}


This is the html, here, close button is on the footer section as a post on this sites sugests
<!-- users-add.component.html -->
<div class="container users-add">
  <form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="section">
      <div class="section-header">
        <h4>CODIGO DEL USUARIO</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="section-body">
        <div class="mb-3 form-group">
          <label for="identificationNumber" class="form-label">Número de Identificación</label>
          <input type="text" id="identificationNumber" formControlName="identificationNumber" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': myForm.get('identificationNumber')?.invalid && myForm.get('identificationNumber')?.touched}">
          <div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="myForm.get('identificationNumber')?.invalid && myForm.get('identificationNumber')?.touched">
            Número de Identificación es requerido y solo puede contener números (máximo 25 caracteres).
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section mt-4">
      <div class="section-header">
        <h4>DATOS DEL USUARIO</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="section-body">
        <div class="mb-3 form-group">
          <label for="firstName" class="form-label">Nombres</label>
          <input type="text" id="firstName" formControlName="firstName" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': myForm.get('firstName')?.invalid && myForm.get('firstName')?.touched}">
          <div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="myForm.get('firstName')?.invalid && myForm.get('firstName')?.touched">
            Nombres es requerido y solo puede contener letras y espacios (máximo 100 caracteres).
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3 form-group">
          <label for="lastName" class="form-label">Sobrenombres</label>
          <input type="text" id="lastName" formControlName="lastName" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': myForm.get('lastName')?.invalid && myForm.get('lastName')?.touched}">
          <div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="myForm.get('lastName')?.invalid && myForm.get('lastName')?.touched">
            Sobrenombres es requerido (máximo 100 caracteres).
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3 form-group">
          <label class="form-label">Es UserMaster</label>
          <div class="form-check-group">
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" formControlName="userMaster" id="userMasterYes" value="yes">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="userMasterYes">Sí</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" formControlName="userMaster" id="userMasterNo" value="no" checked>
              <label class="form-check-label" for="userMasterNo">No</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="errorModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="errorModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 translate class="modal-title" id="errorModalLabel">{{ modalHeader }}</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div translate class="modal-body">
        {{ modalMessage }}
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button translate type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">CLOSE</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


I checked all my logic and it is ok, it is bootstrap who has a bug or something.
I tried reseting the form, the modal messages and with dispose.
When I use it with data that already exits, it correctly shows an error message, if I change the data, it gets stuck and shows the first message.

can't reproduce, could you add a stackblitz example

Stack Overflow is English only site. Please use only English when posting here. That includes comments.

You should initialize modal once, remove and add event listeners to reset the form and use bind listener context. You can try in this way
private modal: bootstrap.Modal | null = null;
private modalElement: HTMLElement | null = null;
//...
constructor(){
//...
//at the end of constructor add
this.modalElement = document.getElementById('errorModal');
if (this.modalElement) {
    this.modal = new bootstrap.Modal(this.modalElement);
  }
}

//showModal updated:
private showModal(message: string, header: string): void {
    this.modalMessage = message;
    this.modalHeader = header;

    if (this.modal && this.modalElement) {
      this.modal.show();

      // Remove all event listeners to prevent multiple bindings
      this.modalElement.removeEventListener('hidden.bs.modal', this.resetFormListener);

      // Add event listener to reset form when modal is closed
      this.modalElement.addEventListener('hidden.bs.modal', this.resetFormListener.bind(this), { once: true });
    } else {
      console.error('No se encontró el elemento modal con id "errorModal".');
    }
  }

  private resetFormListener(): void {
    if (this.modalHeader === 'Éxito') {
      this.resetForm();
    }
  }

